# Exporting to csv for a POJO with List

Tags: java, csv, jackson, jackson-dataformat-csv

I have a POJO with a List within it. I am trying to export the POJO to CSV data. Used jackson-dataformat-csv 2.6.3 library to do it. But failed to write the list values to it. Is there a way to do it.

```
Class ABC { 
String name;
List<DEF> list = new ArrayList();
//getters and setters
}
```

// Code to export or write to output stream

```
CsvMapper lCsvMapper = new CsvMapper();
CsvSchema lCsvSchema = lCsvMapper.schemaFor(ABC.class).withHeader();
//inputData is the ABC instance 
lCsvMapper.writer(lCsvSchema).writeValue(aInOutputStream, inputData);
```

Comment: Jackson seems to only support serialization of nested List / arrays of "scalar" types (numbers and Strings) to CSV, dut to limitations of the CSV format itself. An obvious obstacle here, is you can't set CsvSchemas for both ABC and DEF classes

Comment: I tried with custom CsvSchema builder by adding columns to CsvSchema manually. It seems this is the only choice till now.